# How to Thrown an error if filter is not defined

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm using api filter with SSymfony6, and i have an user entity, looking like this one :

User

- id
- username
- email
- description
- isStaff
- ...

I have a working platform api linked to this entity, with this filters :
ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['id' => 'exact', 'username' => 'exact', 'email' => 'exact'])]

So actually, the only filters configured are on id, username and email

but if I go to /api/users, with this :
/api/users?username=foo&description=bar

I got all my 'foo' users, and description is ignored

I want to throw an error instead of ignoring it, how can i do this ?

thanks

i've try to seek on github issues and stack overflow questions, but I can't find something right about this

Comment: I don't know the platform, but have you seen this?
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/#converting-php-exceptions-to-http-errors